# How to get container id of a docker service

Tags: docker

I want to get a container ID of docker service.
Is there any command available for this ?

I tried

```
docker service ps MyService
```

but this one only gives the service ID, I am interested in the container id in which the service is running

Answer (score 32):

try combination of docker process [filtering](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#filtering) and [formatting](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#formatting):

```
docker ps -f name=YOUR_SERVICE_NAME --format "{{.ID}}"
```

**UPDATE**

thanks to [ahivert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6287489/ahivert) for even shorter solution:

```
# same behavior with
docker ps -f name=YOUR_SERVICE_NAME --quiet
```

Comment: docker ps will not find any container running on other than leader node.

Comment: We have some tooling (python invoke tasks.py based) to query docker swarm for given task metadata, find the node it runs at and finally use docker context (with agreed name based on cluster-id and host/node name) to target the node where the container really runs. In case there is scale other than 1, we pick the first one.

Comment: I get an empty list just the headings when I try `docker ps -f name=YOUR_SERVICE_NAME --format "{{.ID}}"`.  @Andriy what do you think of my question: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/12924/how-to-get-the-ids-of-docker-containers-that-belong-to-a-service-given-the-serv

Answer (score 13):

try from

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31369

`for f in $(docker service ps -q $service);do docker inspect --format '{{.NodeID}} {{.Status.ContainerStatus.ContainerID}}' $f; done`

and

`docker network inspect --verbose`

from https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/31710

Comment: Useful template in this regard is '{{json .}}'. It shows which fields are available.

Comment: I added a filter for running only:
```for f in $(docker service ps -q $service -f "desired-state=running");do docker inspect --format '{{.NodeID}} {{.Status.ContainerStatus.ContainerID}}' $f; done```

Comment: why isn't there a built-in simple standard command from docker itself to list the containers that make up a service?

Comment: honestly why is there not a simple command for this?  Why would one have to remember a for loop script command?

Surely a Docker service simply contains one or more containers. How hard is it to just be able to list them with a simple command.

Comment: I tried both for loop commands in the answer and in the comment and neither worked for me, I'm using Docker version 19.03.  Any placeholders for real values in those commands: Am I supposed to replace any of the text with actual valiues or is it all as it should be? I've written my own question about getting the Docker Container ID from the Service ID here: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/12924/how-to-get-the-ids-of-docker-containers-that-belong-to-a-service-given-the-serv

Answer (score 6):

```
docker service ps -q -f desired-state=running SERVICE_NAME  | xargs docker inspect --format '{{.Status.ContainerStatus.ContainerID}}'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: First part (before |) finds the task ID, second uses task id and retrieves contained id from it via docker inspect. While it looks pretty verbose compared to other solutions I personally think that this approach is most reliable

Answer (score 1):

```
docker ps | grep "<service-name>\." | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: This solution is better because you can use service name like " myservice_db" to differentiate it from "demo_myservice_db" which `docker ps -f name` cannot handle

Answer (score 1):

I tried this, it gives me a list of running services:

```
docker container ls
```

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me. Good job!